# how to pass arguments with newcommand?

Tags: macros, color

I want to set a color argument which will be defined at the start of the document, and changed everywhere else needed. The command `\setcolor` as illustrated below just prints the value 'red' instead of saving it. Thus `\color{\setcolor}` obviously fails.

I think that `\renewcommand` should be involved somehow, but I am confused about how to do it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\setcolor}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}    
    \setcolor{red}
    \color{\setcolor}{some sample text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So essentially you want a variable which containts the name of a color and be able to change it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way.  `\setcolor` is the macro that changes the stored variable `\mycolor`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\setcolor[1]{\def\mycolor{#1}}
\newcommand\mycolor{black}
\begin{document}  
Before text.
\setcolor{red}%
\textcolor{\mycolor}{some temporary sample text}
after text.

\color{\mycolor}
Now it is permanent.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what your use case is here, the normal usage would be to use a colour name that you can redefine as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{zz}{rgb}{1,0,0}

\begin{document}    

    \textcolor{zz}{some sample text}


{\definecolor{zz}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\textcolor{zz}{some sample text}

}

\textcolor{zz}{some sample text}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way where you can give an optional argument for changing the colour and a mandatory argument to which the colour is applied.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mysetcolor}{magenta}% default
\newcommand{\setcolor}[2][]{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \else%
        \renewcommand\mysetcolor{#1}%
    \fi%
    \textcolor{\mysetcolor}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}    
\noindent
\setcolor{some default colored sample text}\\
\setcolor[red]{some red sample text}\\
\setcolor{some sample text with the same color as the one used before}\\
\setcolor[green]{some green sample text}
\end{document}
```

[image]